# Symbols instead of numbers as footnote markers

Tags: symbols, numbering, footnotes

How can I make LaTeX use symbols (*, †, ‡, and so on) instead of numbers to mark footnotes?  (The numbers are confusing because I use superscripted numbers for citations.)

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78221/changing-footnote-symbols

Comment: The solutions below DO NOT work if there is a `minipage` is involved. In that case, please refer to: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18499/how-to-change-symbol-for-footnote-in-minipage

Answer (score 175, accepted):

Use the [`footmisc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/footmisc) package, with option `symbol`.

here is small example:

```
\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}

\footnote[num]{text}
```

instead of `num` you can put the number of the symbol you like:

```
1   asterisk        *   2   dagger      †   3   double dagger       ‡
4   section symbol  §   5   paragraph   ¶   6   parallel lines      ‖
7   two asterisks   **  8   two daggers ††  9   two double daggers  ‡‡
```

Comment: The starred option `symbol*` might also be useful.

Comment: This answer would be better if you gave some code.

Comment: @FlybyNight: Yes (feel free to edit!), but in the meantime you can read "texdoc footmisc" for documentation.

Comment: \usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
will do it.

Comment: The      \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}} should go right before the footnote or in the preamble?

Comment: some code added

Comment: what if we want to use both symbols and numbers?

Comment: I don't see the point of the `\renewcommand{}`. It's not mentioned in the `footmisc` manual, and it works without it.

Answer (score 198):

This can be done by redefining the output of the footnote counter:

```
\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
```

If you would like to switch back to Arabic numbering, you can do it by

```
\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}
```

especially if limiting by grouping (curly braces) would cover a too wide scope.

It may be desirable to reset the counter after such a change, such as by

```
\setcounter{footnote}{0}
```

Comment: I like this method, since you can easily turn off symbols again with another `\renewcommand`.

Comment: I like this simply because it doesn't require a package (i.e. it can be used even on systems where you don't administrate installed packages).

Comment: As an additional upside to this suggestion over the one selected as correct, I will point out that this will work just fine with Beamer. The selected answer did not when I tried it.

Comment: I've tried this method using `scrartcl` and I only obtained sequences of asterisks for footnote symbols. Do you know why that happened? With `footmisc` it did work.

Answer (score 40):

You may also want to reset the footnote counter for each page. People are not familiar with the symbols beyond the double dagger, and more than (at most) 16 footnotes in a single chapter will result in an error message. To reset the counter per page, either use the footmisc option `perpage` or the following code:

```
\usepackage{perpage}
\MakePerPage{footnote}
```

Comment: Of course, this will not solve the problem that the original question asked about. That said, it is a very good idea to add this if you follow either Stefan Kottwitz's answer or the one selected as correct.

Comment: Note that there is already an option in the `footmisc` package itself to achieve the same effect `\usepackage[perpage, symbol*]{footmisc}`

Answer (score 13):

Here is some code I used a long time ago:

```
\@addtoreset{footnote}{page}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\ifcase\value{footnote}\or(*)\or
(**)\or(***)\or(****)\or(\#)\or(\#\#)\or(\#\#\#)\or(\#\#\#\#)\or($\infty$)\fi}
```

The first line should be between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

Comment: of course, "\@addtoreset{footnote}{page}" is pretty unreliable.  if you really want perpage, you need a package to do it for you (the coding is tedious); see lockstep's response for packages to use, and how.

Comment: This is what I was searching for. But I put `($*$)` in place of `(*)` to have the stars vertically centered.

Answer (score 9):

To get a huge number of footnote(-symbols) you could use the [`alphalph`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/alphalph) package.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `fontawesome` package and instead of numbers use icons it provides like this:

```
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\color{white}{\faGears}}
```

or like this for minipage, mdframed etc...

```
\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\color{white}{\faGears}}
```

In the code above `\faGears` is an icon name. You can find more icons in the [CTAN documentation](http://ctan.ijs.si/tex-archive/fonts/fontawesome/doc/fontawesome.pdf).

Comment: `\color{<color>}` is a switch so the following pair of braces is useless. Maybe you are mistaking it for`\textcolor{<color>}{<text>}`. Besides that: doesn't use your code the *same* symbol for every footnote?

Comment: Exscuse me if I'm intruding. If I want to write a book and want to make sure that footnotes are marked with a `\diamond{footnote number}` -command while citation notes of texts (bibliography) are marked with a `\box{ footnote number}` and, if you want to change your mind, by a `\circle{footnote number}`.
Thank you