# How to change symbol for footnote in minipage

Tags: numbering, footnotes, minipage

`\renewcommand` method does not work

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{1.3\textwidth}

test this\footnote{abc}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

In the following example the footnote number is incorrect. Why?

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\arabic{mpfootnote}}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
test this\footnotemark
\footnotetext{abc}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Change `\thempfootnote`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\arabic{mpfootnote}}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
test this\footnote{abc}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: small typo `\arabic{mpfootnote}` should be `\arabic{footnote}` right?

Comment: @colinfang: NO, there are two footnote counters, `footnote` for the normal footnotes and `mpfootnote` inside minipages. The last one is zeroed every time a minipage is entered. It is therefor a BAD idea to change it to `\arabic`, because you can end up with different footnotes with the same number on one page.

Comment: @Danie - Can u check my updated question?

Comment: @colinfang: please look at the explanation below

Comment: So, `mp` here means `minipage`?

Answer (score 10):

If your objective is to just continue with the "global" footnotes through a minipage then look at the example below. It illustrates the two different footnotes and how to use both inside a minipage.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{footmisc}% for \footref and \mpfootnotemark
\begin{document}
\noindent\ldots{} main text\footnote{Before minipage} \ldots\par
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    Footnotes in minipages are numbered using
    lowercase letters\footnote{Inside minipage\label{fn:1}}.\\
    To reuse the previous minipage footnote\footref{fn:1}.\\
    A second minipage footnote\footnote{Again}.\\
    A footnote to use global\footnotemark.\\
    A second global footnote\footnotemark.
\end{minipage}}
%--- Directly after minipage ----------------------------
\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
\footnotetext{First global footnote inside minipage}%
\stepcounter{footnote}%
\footnotetext{Second global footnote inside minipage}%
%--------------------------------------------------------
\par
\noindent\ldots{} main text\footnote{After minipage} \ldots\par
\end{document}
```

If you want all footnotes to be numeric then you must set the `mpfootnote` counter at the begining of the minipage and reset the `footnote` counter at the end. Please do not now use `\footnotemark` inside the minipage, because it will mess up everything.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent\ldots{} main text\footnote{Before minipage} \ldots\par
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
        \setcounter{mpfootnote}{\value{footnote}}%
        \renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\arabic{mpfootnote}}%
    Footnotes in minipages\footnote{Inside minipage}.\\
    A second minipage footnote\footnote{Again}.
        \setcounter{footnote}{\value{mpfootnote}}%
\end{minipage}}
\par
\noindent\ldots{} main text\footnote{After minipage} \ldots\par
\end{document}
```

Comment: great examples

Comment: How can I use the footnote label defined in one table within another table?