# table notes in English typography

Tags: tables, footnotes, typography

I'm using the code given below:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\footnote{real footnote}
\begin{table}[!ht]\centering
\caption{Title}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
\centering\small
\begin{tabular}{ll} 
A & B \\ 
name  & age \footnotemark \\ 
size & height \footnotemark  \\ 
\end{tabular}
\footnotetext[2]{table note}
\footnotetext[4]{table note}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

and I have three questions:

1. does this comply with English typographic rules?
2. if yes, why does `\footnotetext[2]{table note}` yield a `b` and `2` for the numbering?
3. should not I control the width of the minipage to have the table notes appear right under the table and not on the left as in the current version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are already using a `minipage`, as you do, you can insert footnotes directly into the table, without calling the `\footnotemark` and the the `footnotetext`. This way, you would have a coherent numbering throughout (i.e. letters).

Then, regarding your other questions: I don't know about (1), I think it depends on styles, but you should perhaps ask on English SX; about (3), yes I think it would look better to make the `minipage` the same width as the table (but if the real table is this small, perhaps you should stretch the columns too).

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\footnote{real footnote}
\begin{table}[!ht]\centering
\caption{Title}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.2\textwidth}
\centering\small
\begin{tabular}{ll} 
A & B \\ 
name  & age \footnote[2]{table note} \\ 
size & height \footnote[4]{table note}  \\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have to investigate for the letters because I would like symbols instead.

Comment: @pluton Yes, I think they are the default for `minipage` footnotes, but you can undoubtedly change that. See [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18500/10119) for how to do it.

Comment: The thing is that with this solution, the vertical space between the end of the table and the footnotes is too large.

Comment: @pluton Add this to your preamble: `\makeatletter
\setlength{\skip\@mpfootins}{5.5pt}
\makeatother`. The second argument can be any length you like.