# Footenote in table appear only as alpha letters

Tags: tables, footnotes

I'm trying to add footnotes to a table with arabic numerals, but it comes up as alpha letters instead:

```
begin{minipage}{500pt}   
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}
\begin{tabular}{rcccc} \\ \hline
\noalign{\vskip 1mm}  
\multicolumn{5}{c}{\ce{Fe(NO)3\cdot9H2O}} \\ 
Trials & $m_o$\footnote{\scriptsize Mass of capillary} & $m$\footnote{\scriptsize Mass of capillary and sample} & $L$\footnote{\scriptsize Length} & $R$\footnote{\scriptsize Magnetic balance reading of sample} \\ \hline
1 & \SI{0.1873}{g} & \SI{0.2345}{g} & \SI{3.56}{cm} & 414 \\
2 & \SI{0.1914}{g} & \SI{0.2340}{g} & \SI{3.56}{cm} & 414 \\
3 & \SI{0.1827}{g} & \SI{0.2180}{g} & \SI{3.56}{cm} & 414 \\
4 & \SI{0.1881}{g} & \SI{0.2193}{g} & \SI{3.56}{cm} & 414 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: In `minipage` environments, the relevant counter is called `mpfootnote`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Thanks! that worked. I had to look up mpfootnote, but here is the [solution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18499/how-to-change-symbol-for-footnote-in-minipage):