# supertabular and simple footnote customization

Tags: footnotes, supertabular

I have a problem defining customization for footnotes marks (arabic, roman etc) inside a `mpsupertabular`.

In the Minimal working example I would expect the footnote mark to appear in `\roman` (i, ii, ...) but instead it appears in `\alph` (a, b, ...). I tried the same with `\arabic` (1,2,...) but I still get `\alph`.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,a4paper]{article}

% Compile with xelatex

\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}

% https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Footnotes_and_Margin_Notes#Customization
% \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\roman{footnote}}

\begin{document}

%\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{3}
%\setlength\tabcolsep{1pt}

\begin{mpsupertabular}{ c c }

lalalala & lololololo \\
lalalala & lololololo \\
lalalala & lololololo \\
lalalala & lololololo \\
lalalala & lololololo \\
lalalala & lololololo \footnote{Awesome footnote}  \\
lalalala & lololololo \\
lalalala & lololololo \\
lalalala & lololololo \\
lalalala & lololololo \\
lalalala & lololololo \\
lalalala & lololololo \\
lalalala & lololololo \\
lalalala & lololololo \\

\end{mpsupertabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: alph instead of roman footnote mark]

PS I am not interested in switching the `supertabular` to something else.

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: @Joce, I edited the post to clarify the problem. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is caused because `mpsupertabular` is placed on a `minipage`. See [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18499/how-to-change-symbol-for-footnote-in-minipage) answer for a more elaborate explanation.

## Old result

[image]

Using the suggestion from [Leo Lui](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18499/how-to-change-symbol-for-footnote-in-minipage): `\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\arabic{mpfootnote}}`, we get:

## New result

[image]

## MWE

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,a4paper]{article}
% Compile with xelatex

\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}

% https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Footnotes_and_Margin_Notes#Customization
\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\roman{mpfootnote}}

\begin{document}

\section{\texttt{minipage}}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
Test\footnote{\texttt{minipage}}
\end{minipage}

\section{\texttt{mpsupertabulartest}}
\begin{mpsupertabular}{ c c }
lalalala & lololololo \footnote{\texttt{mpsupertabular}}  \\
\end{mpsupertabular}

\end{document}
```