# Footnote marker as symbol in image caption

Tags: graphics, captions, footnotes

I am using the following in the preamble of my document to get symbols instead of numbers as footnote markers:

```
\usepackage{perpage}
\MakePerPage{footnote}
\usepackage{footmisc}[perpage,symbol*]
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
```

For some obscure reason I need both `perpage` package and option for the per-page footnote counter reset to work... And it works with no problem.

But then if I make a footnote in the caption of an image, the marker will go back to alphabetical. Is there a way to alter that behavior as well?

Comment: If I remember correctly, `\caption` does use a minipage (-like) setting, which means that `\footnote` is actually controlled by `\thempfootnote` settings

Comment: Hence the answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18499/how-to-change-symbol-for-footnote-in-minipage

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Christian in the comments, the footnotes under a `\caption` are controlled by `\thempfootnote` and not `\thefootnote`. So, you need to renew that command as well:

```
\usepackage{perpage}
\MakePerPage{footnote}
\usepackage{footmisc}[perpage,symbol*]
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}} % the new setting
```