# How to change the footnote symbol in Beamer block

Tags: beamer, footnotes

I want to change the footnote symbol in block of Beamer.

I used the following command.

```
\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
```

Then Symbols of thanks and footnote not used in block ware changed.
But Symbols of footnote used in block weren't changed.

Please tell me how to change them?

I'm a Japanese Student so, I want you to forgive small mistakes about English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the same trick as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18500/36296

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\ifcase\value{mpfootnote}\or\textasteriskcentered\or\textdagger\or\textdaggerdbl\fi}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
  \begin{block}{title}
  content\footnote{text}
  \end{block}

    abc\footnote{test}
  
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```