# Changing footnote symbols

Tags: symbols, footnotes

I was wondering if there is way to change the symbols of footnotes to any symbol  I want. I know there are some packages that put away the numbers and use predefined symbols, but I want to use some arbitrary symbol. Is there a way?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! "Arbitrary" is a bit too vague, may you be more specific?

Comment: Thank you. \Mobilefone,  \Telefon, \chi, \frownie, etc. Just any symbol.

Comment: Related Question: [Changing footnote symbol within mdframed](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175951/changing-footnote-symbol-within-mdframed).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The footnote symbol code is actually very simple:

```
\def\@fnsymbol#1{\ensuremath{\ifcase#1\or *\or \dagger\or \ddagger\or
   \mathsection\or \mathparagraph\or \|\or **\or \dagger\dagger
   \or \ddagger\ddagger \else\@ctrerr\fi}}
```

So, if you were to copy that definition and replace `\ddagger` by `\forall`, then the third footnote would get an inverted A.

Do not forget to actually change the footnote counter to `fnsymbol`:

```
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
```

Comment: Note that if you redefine \@fnsymbol, you need to preceded the command above by a "\makeatletter" and follow it with a "\makeatother".

Comment: @thymaro, counting to three is difficult, it seems:-)

Comment: No offense. I read the answer and was confused as to why the second one should be changing and figured I just didn't get it. After going through the code with a little more care, I noticed why my understanding didn't align with what was written. Then, I decided other people might be as offset (p.i.) as me when reading the answer, so I changed it. Happy Easter! :D

Comment: @thymaro that's fine thanks for the edit, I never mind if typos and falsehoods get edited out of my answers, that's how the site is supposed to work..

Comment: your method may work for this https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/471861/41144, if so, feel free to comment?

Answer (score 21):

As starting point the definition of `\@fnsymbol` can be used (`latex.ltx`, [`source2e.pdf`: "21 Counter and Lengths"](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf#page=111).
The following example goes a step further and removes the upper limit for the counter value. If needed the symbol will be multiplied (see the doubling of symbols in `\@fnsymbol`) with the help of package `alphalph`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\myfnsymbolsingle}[1]{%
  \ensuremath{%
    \ifcase#1% 0
    \or % 1
      *%   
    \or % 2
      \dagger
    \or % 3  
      \ddagger
    \or % 4   
      \mathsection
    \or % 5
      \mathparagraph
    \else % >= 6
      \@ctrerr  
    \fi
  }%   
}   
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\myfnsymbol}[1]{%
  \myfnsymbolsingle{\value{#1}}%
}

% remove upper boundary by multiplying the symbols if needed
\usepackage{alphalph}
\newalphalph{\myfnsymbolmult}[mult]{\myfnsymbolsingle}{}

\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{%
  \myfnsymbolmult{\value{footnote}}%
}

\begin{document}
\footnote{a}\footnote{b}\footnote{c}\footnote{d}\footnote{e}%
\footnote{f}\footnote{g}\footnote{h}\footnote{i}\footnote{j}%
\footnote{k}\footnote{l}\footnote{m}\footnote{n}\footnote{o}%
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Works in Beamer too! (Yes, I know footnotes are bad :)

Comment: your method may work for this https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/471861/41144, if so, feel free to comment?

Comment: @nate, a matter of opinion. I find footnotes to be pleasant hunting grounds for comments, asides, speculations, humor, etc. Gibbon's "Decline and Fall" would lose much of its interest without its footnotes.

Answer (score 16):

I found these explanations a bit confusing. I wanted `$\star$` as a footnote symbol, so I just did

```
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{$\star$}
```

and now I get what I want on the next footnote.

I assume that this generalizes to any symbol `X` by writing

```
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{X}
```

Comment: While this might work, it also fixes the footnote symbol to `$\star$` for all subsequent footnotes.

Answer (score 14):

You can use [`footmisc`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/footmisc) and define a set of symbols with `\DefineFNsymbols` (text-only symbols, i.e. no math) and `\DefineFNsymbolsTM` (for text or math symbols)

```
\DefineFNsymbolsTM{myfnsymbols}{% def. from footmisc.sty "bringhurst" symbols
  \textasteriskcentered *
  \textdagger    \dagger
  \textdaggerdbl \ddagger
  \textsection   \mathsection
  \textbardbl    \|%
  \textparagraph \mathparagraph
}%
```

And call it with

```
\setfnsymbol{myfnsymbols}
```

Here's a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[symbol*]{footmisc}
\DefineFNsymbolsTM{myfnsymbols}{% def. from footmisc.sty "bringhurst" symbols
  \textasteriskcentered *
  \textdagger    \dagger
  \textdaggerdbl \ddagger
  \textsection   \mathsection
  \textbardbl    \|%
  \textparagraph \mathparagraph
}%
\setfnsymbol{myfnsymbols}
\begin{document}
\footnote{a}\footnote{b}\footnote{c}
\footnote{d}\footnote{e}\footnote{f}
\end{document}
```

[image: footmisc footnote symbols example]