# Changing footnote symbol within mdframed

Tags: footnotes, mdframed

Am having difficulty changing the footnote symbol, especially within an [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) environment.

I thought I was done when I came across [Changing footnote symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78221/changing-footnote-symbols), but the accepted solution (commented out in the MWE) does not seem to work for me.  Then I tried the

```
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{$\dagger$}
```

which seems to work, but not inside an `mdframed` environment, even if I issue the `\renewcommand` after the `\begin{mdframed}`:

[image]

### References:

- [Changing footnote symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78221/changing-footnote-symbols)

### Notes:

- For this particular use case I really *only* want one symbol. But having a solution that actually works and allows for multiple symbols is fine with me.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[textheight=3cm, textwidth=9cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mdframed}

%% This at least produces the dagger outside of mdframed
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{$\dagger$}%

%%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78221/changing-footnote-symbols
%%% This yields a numerical value outside of mdframed and an alphabetical foot note inside mdframed
%\makeatletter
%\def\@fnsymbol#1{\ensuremath{\ifcase#1\or *\or \dagger\or \ddagger\or
%   \mathsection\or \mathparagraph\or \|\or **\or \dagger\dagger
%   \or \ddagger\ddagger \else\@ctrerr\fi}}
%\makeatother


\begin{document}

This\footnote{Outside of Mdframed a dagger is used as desired.} is a footnote outside of mdframed.

\begin{mdframed}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{$\dagger$}% <-- This seems to have no effect.
This\footnote{Want a dagger for footnotes inside of Mdframed} is a footnote inside mdframed.
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Footnotes inside a `mdframed` are treated as inside a `minipage`, so `\thempfootnote` is used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[textheight=3cm, textwidth=9cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mdframed}

%% This at least produces the dagger outside of mdframed
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{$\dagger$}%

%%% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78221/changing-footnote-symbols
%%% This yields a numerical value outside of mdframed and an alphabetical foot note inside mdframed
%\makeatletter
%\def\@fnsymbol#1{\ensuremath{\ifcase#1\or *\or \dagger\or \ddagger\or
%   \mathsection\or \mathparagraph\or \|\or **\or \dagger\dagger
%   \or \ddagger\ddagger \else\@ctrerr\fi}}
%\makeatother


\begin{document}

This\footnote{Outside of Mdframed a dagger is used as desired.} is a footnote outside of mdframed.

\begin{mdframed}
\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{$\dagger$}% <-- This will now have an effect.
This\footnote{Want a dagger for footnotes inside of Mdframed} is a footnote inside mdframed.
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you can make the definition based on a set of symbols and apply it either only to footnotes inside `mdframed` (as in my example just below) or to all footnotes (as in the example at the bottom):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[textheight=6cm, textwidth=9cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginEnvironment{mdframed}{%
\def\@fnsymbol#1{\ensuremath{\ifcase#1\or \dagger\or \ddagger\or
   \mathsection\or \mathparagraph\or \|\or **\or \dagger\dagger
   \or \ddagger\ddagger \else\@ctrerr\fi}}%
}   
\renewcommand\thempfootnote{\fnsymbol{mpfootnote}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This\footnote{I have a regular marker for this footnote outside of \texttt{mdframed}} is a footnote outside mdframed.

\begin{mdframed}
This\footnote{I have a \texttt{dagger} for this footnote inside of \texttt{mdframed}} is a footnote inside mdframed.
This\footnote{I have a \texttt{ddagger} for this footnote inside of \texttt{mdframed}} is a footnote inside mdframed.
This\footnote{I have a \texttt{mathsection} for this footnote inside of \texttt{mdframed}} is a footnote inside mdframed.
\end{mdframed}

This\footnote{I have a regular marker for this footnote outside of \texttt{mdframed}} is a footnote outside mdframed.

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[textheight=6cm, textwidth=9cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\def\@fnsymbol#1{\ensuremath{\ifcase#1\or \dagger\or \ddagger\or
   \mathsection\or \mathparagraph\or \|\or **\or \dagger\dagger
   \or \ddagger\ddagger \else\@ctrerr\fi}}%
\renewcommand\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}   
\renewcommand\thempfootnote{\fnsymbol{mpfootnote}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This\footnote{I have a \texttt{dagger} for this footnote outside of \texttt{mdframed}} is a footnote outside mdframed.

\begin{mdframed}
This\footnote{I have a \texttt{dagger} for this footnote inside of \texttt{mdframed}} is a footnote inside mdframed.
This\footnote{I have a \texttt{ddagger} for this footnote inside of \texttt{mdframed}} is a footnote inside mdframed.
This\footnote{I have a \texttt{mathsection} for this footnote inside of \texttt{mdframed}} is a footnote inside mdframed.
\end{mdframed}

This\footnote{I have a \texttt{ddagger} for this footnote outside of \texttt{mdframed}} is a footnote outside mdframed.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If it is easy can you also add how to change the footnote outside the mdframed as well. I don't need it, but that will complete all the possible options.  Using the obvious `\renewcommand\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{mpfootnote}}` does _not_ work.

Comment: @PeterGrill I've added this option in my updated answer.

Comment: Very compliments for your answer.