# Symbols of footnotes not raised inside mdframed

Tags: footnotes, memoir, mdframed

I want to change the symbols of footnotes inside mdframed.  I found there is quite simple solution for that, in this very [very helpful answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175951/changing-footnote-symbol-within-mdframed) to the same problem.

I applied it and it works but the symbols, asterinks, daggers etc, are aligned to the text and not raised as the footnotes usually are.

I tried to raise them with raisebox

```
\documentclass[9pt,twoside,openright,showtrims]{memoir} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathspec,xltxtra}
\usepackage{url,graphicx}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{layouts}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tablefootnote} 
\usepackage[framemethod=PSTricks,tikz]{mdframed}


\makeatletter
\AtBeginEnvironment{mdframed}{%
\def\@fnsymbol#1{\ensuremath{\ifcase#1\or \dagger\or \ddagger\or
\mathsection\or \mathparagraph\or \|\or **\or \dagger\dagger
\or \ddagger\ddagger \else\@ctrerr\fi}}%
}   
\renewcommand\thempfootnote{\raisebox{.8ex}{\small \fnsymbol{mpfootnote}}}
\makeatother
```

but i get errors. The asterisk is raised in the mark but i get this at the end of the frame.

[image]

Actually, i had the same problem even before i changed the numbering to symbols. By default, the numbering was a, b, c..., even then, they were not raised.

Do you have any ideas for a way to raise them without errors?

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! :) I am willing to bet your problem is because you're using `xltxtra`: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/80028/. The package redefines `\textsuperscript`…

Comment: wow, that was quick!  you are absolutely right, i removed the xlxtra package, but now i' m wondering if something else 'breaks' without this package, that i fail to notice right now, the funny is that i can't remember why i used at first

Comment: Probably not. But to be sure you can load `xltxtra` with the `no-sscript` option if you like `\usepackage[no-sscript]{xltxtra}`. On the other hand: if you don't even know why you're loading it you might as well leave it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't `mdframed` but `xltxtra`. the latter redefines `\textsuperscript` (and `\textsubscript`) to use real superior figures instead of normal figures in a smaller font size. This only works reliably if a font has the glyphs available: [superscripts with xelatex? (footnotes, natbib)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76470/) The package does define starred variants of both commands through which the original definitions are available.

Since the footnote mark is placed with `\textsuperscript` you get the problems here. One solution is to load the package with the `no-sscript` option.

```
\usepackage[no-sscript]{xltxtra}
```

This swaps the definitions: `\textsuperscript` gives the original definition, `\textsuperscript*` the one for the superior figures.

The other solution of course is not to use the package at all.

Comment: `s/other solution/best solution/`