# Footnotes in multipage environments

Tags: environments, footnotes, mdframed

I'm in conflict with how [`mdframed`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed?lang=en) handles footnotes inside environments that span multiple pages. Consider this MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\newmdenv[%
    hidealllines=true,
    backgroundcolor=blue!10,
]{bluebox}

\begin{document}
\begin{bluebox}
\lipsum[1]
Here comes a footnote.\footnote{Footnote 1.}
\lipsum[2]
Here comes another footnote.\footnotemark
\lipsum[3-5]
\end{bluebox}
\footnotetext{Footnote 2.}
\end{document}
```

which outputs
[image]
[image]

My preferred behavior would be for footnotes to appear inside the blue box, but with the same counting scheme (1, 2, 3, ...) as outside the environment *and* on the same page as the reference in the text. Any ideas how to implement this?

Comment: that isn't really default behaviour, it must be specific footnote code in mdframed package, I assume.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Changed my wording.

Answer (score 1):

The problem as I understand is to have the output as shown in this picture:
[image: footnotes in bluebox with alphabetic numbering]

To produce this with a arabic numbering as seen here:

[image: desired outcome]

adjust the counter

```
\thempfootnote
```

as shown in the code for the desired outcome:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\newmdenv[%
hidealllines=true,
backgroundcolor=blue!10,
]{bluebox}

\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\arabic{mpfootnote}}% <-- This changes to arabic numbers.
\begin{document}

    \begin{bluebox}
        \lipsum[1]
        Here comes a footnote.\footnote{Footnote 1.}
        \lipsum[2]
        Here comes another footnote.\footnote{Footnote 2.}
        \lipsum[3-5]
    \end{bluebox}

\end{document}
```

see also [Gonzalo's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/175952/100482) or [Leo's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18500/100482) answers regarding footnotes on which I based the above code.

EDIT:
A rather crude, but working way would be:

```
\enlargethispage{3cm}
\begin{bluebox}
    \lipsum[1]
    Here comes a footnote.\footnote{Footnote 1.}
    \lipsum[2]
    Here comes another footnote.\footnote{Footnote 2.}
    \lipsum[3-5]
\end{bluebox}
\clearpage
```

Comment: Yes, but the footnotes should also move up a page to appear at the bottom of the blue box on the first page since that is the page they are referenced on.

Comment: @Casimir: well, I tried to pack everything inside a minipage, but that only messed up the pagination.