# Creating customized footnotes

Tags: footnotes

There are some strange footnotes in text that look like this:

[image: strange footnotes]

in text:

[image]

At the university, we were given a task to remake in LaTeX a very old Soviet book on mathematical analysis by Grigoriy Fichtenholz. So I found these footnotes in the text. And they are everywhere. And I don't know what to do with them. Is there any command to change style of `\footnote`? Or there is some special way?

Comment: Just two footnotes or all of them?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you also show how the footnote marker appears in the text?

Comment: I added one more screenshot

Comment: See [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/826/symbols-instead-of-numbers-as-footnote-markers?rq=1) and [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78221/changing-footnote-symbols?lq=1).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can work only if you use a “per page” numbering of footnotes. Next, the typesetting of the marker must be modified.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% three should be sufficient
\DefineFNsymbols*{asterisks}{*{**}{***}}
\setfnsymbol{asterisks}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
% we want a nonbreaking space before the marker in text
\preto\footnote{\unskip~}
% we want the marker normal size and not superscripted, with )
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makefnmark}{\mbox{\normalfont\@thefnmark})}
\settowidth{\footnotemargin}{***) }
\patchcmd{\@makefntext}{\hss\@makefnmark}{\hss \@makefnmark\ }{}{}
\makeatother

\textheight=2cm % just for the example

\begin{document}

First footnote\footnote{Some long text that should wrap
across at least two lines; just add text just add text
just add text just add text just add text.}.
Now another footnote just to see what happens\footnote{Try this.}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh wow. This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: and another question: How do I reset style of footnotes back to numeric?

Comment: @DmitryVolobuev That's a completely different question; please ask a new one with all the needed details. Do you want two different sets of footnotes?

Comment: Yep. I need two different sets of footnotes

Comment: [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/298783/100562)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a setup with `\textasteriskcentered` (providing for `*`,`**`,`***` at the moment only) and using `footmisc`.

There's a `wiley` set of `footmisc`, which has `*`, `**` already, but not `***`, if this should be needed at all.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}


\DefineFNsymbols*{asterisks}{\textasteriskcentered{\textasteriskcentered\textasteriskcentered}{\textasteriskcentered\textasteriskcentered\textasteriskcentered}}
\let\origthefootnote\thefootnote
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\origthefootnote)}

\begin{document}
\setfnsymbol{asterisks}
A footnote on foo\footnote{foo} and another footnote on foobar\footnote{foobar} and yet another one\footnote{foobar foo}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Footnotes are not common *, **, *** ... They are look like this *), **), ***), ****), ...

Comment: @DmitryVolobuev: Adding the `)` is easy if they appear this way in text also

Comment: Note, though, that in the original text the `)` seems not to be superscript.

Comment: I have a couple questions. 1) What does the `texcomp` do here? Everything seems work without it. 2) The example above does not work under latex.exe command in MiKTeX: missing `\begin{document}` But it works under texify.exe. Need help!

Comment: @maximav: You're right about `textcomp`. It is not necessary. And I don't use `MikTeX`, so I can't give any solution about that issue. I also don't need such things like `texify`.

Comment: The difference between texify and latex is just a number of passes. latex.exe does 1 time, texify do 2. The command you use for compilation does one/two passes at once automatically?

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand your question, so I'll answer all possible answers :)

---

If you mean to ask how to make a footnote then the answer is using the command

```
\footnote{A strange russian footnote}
```

---

If you mean to ask how to use symbols for your footnote rather than numbers, then the answer would be to add the following to your preamble

```
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
```

---

If you mean to ask how to use *) and then **) as the footnote symbols the answer (as given [HERE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78223/90297)) is you'd have to add The following to your preamble

```
\def\@fnsymbol#1{\ensuremath{\ifcase#1\or *)\or \or **) \or ***) \or  
    \dagger\or \ddagger\or \mathsection\or \mathparagraph\or \|\or \dagger\dagger
    \or \ddagger\ddagger \else\@ctrerr\fi}}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
```

---

Comment: Footnotes are not common  *, **, *** ... 
They are look like this *), **), ***), ****), ...

Comment: I fixed my answer accordingly