# Using more than one set of footnotes

Tags: footnotes

I got three different types of footnotes in text (numneric, asterisk and asterisk  with bracket [*), **), ...]). Can I use all of them in the same time? And how?

Comment: `manyfoot`  https://www.ctan.org/pkg/manyfoot or `bigfoot`  https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bigfoot

Answer (score 1):

You can use the custom footnotes as described in my answer to your previous question [HERE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/298751/90297), and then use the counter to control the sets. For instance put this in your preamble:

```
\def\@fnsymbol#1{\ensuremath{\ifcase#1\or *)\or \or **) \or ***) \or *] \or **] or ***] 
     \or \dagger\or \ddagger\or \mathsection\or \mathparagraph\or \|
     \or \dagger\dagger \or \ddagger\ddagger \else\@ctrerr\fi}}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
```

Then inside the document when you want to use *] simply set the counter to

```
\setcounter{footnote}{3}
```

Now when you use `\footnote{some footnote}` you will get *]. When you want to go back to *) set the counter to 0.
You could use the method depicted [HERE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30605/90297) to go back and forth on sets.