# Tagging equations with different symbols

Tags: equations, tags

I want to put some different symbolic notations after some equations such as `$*$`, `$\dagger$` (see image below), `$\ddagger$` etc.

I did the following

```
\begin{equation*}
a+b=c  \tag{*}
\end{equation*}
```

Output was as expected:

> [image]

For next equation, I wanted to use $\dagger$, and I did following:

```
\begin{equation*}
p+q=r  \tag{\dagger}
\end{equation*}
```

This produced some errors. I then replaced it in following *cheating* way:

```
\begin{equation*}
p+q=r  \tag{ \mbox{ $\dagger$ } }
\end{equation*}
```

This then showed following output as expected:

> [image]

**Question:** So to put the sign of second image, I had to do go in process

> [equation mode] --> [ text mode ] -- > [equation mode]

i.e. first `\begin{equation}`-`\end{equation}`; inside it use `\mbox{ }`; inside it use dollar sign. Isn't this a cheating? What should be correct way to put this sign?

Comment: Just `\tag{$\dagger$}` will do, no?

Comment: Have you tried using `\renewcommand{\theequation}{\fnsymbol{equation}}`?

Comment: @Troy: it was showing errors (I mentioned this; and so finally I did a cheating, which worked!). TeXnician, I have not used it.

Comment: Is there any reason why you would want to manually tag them?

Comment: @Troy: sorry; your answer works; actually, when I put dollar sign inside tag, then it showed in red color, so I felt it will be wrong; but it works. Thanks

Comment: @Texnician: Since I want to cite the equation in paragraph immediate after it and no after the paragraph ; so I thought it would be better to put some signs, insted of numbering them.

Comment: @pGroups What I meant was, there's no need for `\mbox` in your 'cheating' attempt. I'm not sure why , without the `\mbox`, you would still consider it as cheating, though.

Comment: @Troy; you are right; I had not inserted dollar so showing error; but after putting dollar, in the tex file (without run) was showing red dollar symbols - I felt it is wrong; but actually no error comes, and so your command works.

Comment: I meant why you want to manually tag with symbols if latex can make this automatically (to see what I meant with the code look [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78223/124577)).

Answer (score 5):

The argument of the `\tag{<label>}` command from the `amsmath` package is in text mode by default. This is why if you try `\tag{\dagger}`, you get `Missing $ inserted`-like errors.

If you want to tag them with a mathematical symbol, you need to enclose the symbol in a math environment, like `\(...\)`. The `\mbox` is not necessary.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    Tagging in text mode: 
    \begin{equation*}
    a+b=c  \tag{*}
    \end{equation*}
    Tagging in math mode (symbols):
    \[
    p+q=r   \tag{\(\dagger\)} % <------- Note the math environment
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image: simple tagging]