# How can I change font size for \tag in equations?

Tags: equations, tags

Original code is taken from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/365961/127048. Here I want to change font size of a `\tag{}` into a smaller font such as `\footnotesize`.

```tex
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    Tagging in text mode:
    \begin{equation*}
    a+b=c  \footnotesize \tag{a}
    \end{equation*}
    Tagging in math mode (symbols):
    \[
    p+q=r   \footnotesize \tag{\(b\)} % <------- Note the math environment
    \]
\end{document}
```

I have added `\footnotesize` before `\tag{}`.

Instead of `\tag{a}`, when I do `\footnotesize \tag{a}` I am getting following warning message:

`LaTeX Font Warning: Command \footnotesize invalid in math mode on input line 7`.

How can I suppress this warning message while changing font size of a `\tag{}`?

Comment: Should this be a global change, or localised to a single `\tag`?

Comment: Localised would be better option for me. Like in my example I want to localize for both `\tag{a}` and `\tag{b}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\newtagform` of `mathtools` and define an environment where the tags are in footnotesize.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\newtagform{footnotesize}{\footnotesize(}{)}

\newenvironment{smallertags}{\usetagform{footnotesize}}{\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}

Text \eqref{test}

Normal tag
\begin{equation}
a+b=c
\end{equation}

\begin{smallertags}
Smaller tag
\begin{equation}
a+b=c
\end{equation}

Tagging in text mode:
\begin{equation*}\label{test}
a+b=c  \tag{a}
\end{equation*}

Tagging in math mode (symbols):
\[
p+q=r \tag{\(b\)} % <------- Note the math environment
\]
\end{smallertags}

Normal tag
\begin{equation}
a+b=c
\end{equation}

\begin{smallertags}
With alignment\usetagform{footnotesize}
\begin{align}
a&=1 \tag{*} \\
b&=2 \tag{**}
\end{align}
\end{smallertags}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You don't want the reference to be footnote size, do you?

Comment: No sir, the reference could be the normalsize. I just wanted brackets `()` and text inside of it to be footnote size ; `tagging in math mode` is exactly what I was looking for