# How to make bold footnotes

Tags: footnotes, bold

**How can I make bold the symbols and their brackets that I choose for footnotes?**. For example, I don't want this [¶] as the 9th footnote (`\mathparagraph`), but this **[¶]**.

I change Heiko Oberdiek's answer in [that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78221/changing-footnote-symbols) question. The code is below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{wasysym}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\myfnsymbolsingle}[1]{%
    \ensuremath{%
        \ifcase#1% 0
        \or % 1
     *%   
    \or % 2
    \dagger
    \or % 3  
    \twonotes
    \or % 4   
    \mathsection
    \or % 5
    \natural
    \or
    \sharp
    \or
    \ddagger
    \or
    \eighthnote
            \or
    \mathparagraph
        \or % 1
    **%   
    \or % 2
    \dagger\dagger
    \or % 3  
    \twonotes\twonotes
    \or % 4   
    \mathsection\mathsection
    \or % 5
    \natural\natural
    \or
    \sharp\sharp
        \or
    \ddagger\ddagger
    \or
    \eighthnote\eighthnote
        \or
    \mathparagraph\mathparagraph
        \else % >= 6
        \@ctrerr  
        \fi
    }%   
}   
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\myfnsymbol}[1]{%
    \myfnsymbolsingle{\value{#1}}%
}

% remove upper boundary by multiplying the symbols if needed
\usepackage{alphalph}
\newalphalph{\myfnsymbolmult}[mult]{\myfnsymbolsingle}{}

\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{%
    [\myfnsymbolsingle{\value{footnote}}]%
}

\begin{document}
        trrt\footnote{a}

         fghfgh\footnote{b}\footnote{c}\footnote{d}\footnote{e}%
    \footnote{f}\footnote{g}\footnote{h}\footnote{i}\footnote{j}%

    fghfgh\footnote{b}\footnote{c}\footnote{d}\footnote{e}%
    \footnote{f}\footnote{g}\footnote{h}\footnote{i}%
\end{document}
```

How can I do it?

Thanks in advanced!!!

P.S.: And one not so important question: *I believe that the code witch I made has pieces that are not necessary*. Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the following:

```latex
\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{%
    {\mathversion{bold}\bfseries [\myfnsymbolsingle{\value{footnote}}]}%
}
```

should do what you want in principle (and it does for the `\mathparagraph` symbol), but some fonts are not available in bold, so some of the symbols won't be bold in this setup. See warnings such as:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `U/wasy/b/n' in size <6> not available
(Font)              Font shape `U/wasy/m/n' tried instead on input line **.
```

in the log file.

In case things are difficult to distinguish by eye, use `\showoutput` at the end of your document to see the actual fonts used, e.g.:

```latex
.......\mathon
.......\OMS/cmsy/b/n/6 {
.......\OMS/cmsy/b/n/6 {
.......\mathoff
```

This is the double `\mathparagraph` from the last footnote in your example (`\footnote{i}`). Indeed, if, before `\end{document}`, you insert `\show\mathparagraph`, you'll see on the terminal:

```latex
> \mathparagraph=\mathchar"27B.
```

So this is the character with `\mathcode` `"027B` which means an ordinary symbol (class `0` also known as `\mathord`, cf. TeXbook p. 154) from family `2` and position `"7B` in the font encoding (TeX's hexadecimal notation for literal integers). Then, if you insert this:

```latex
{\mathversion{bold}%
 \makeatletter
 \check@mathfonts
 \makeatother
 \showthe\textfont2
}
```

at the same place to see what is math family `2` in `\textstyle` of `\mathversion{bold}` (`\textstyle` because your `\myfnsymbolsingle` makes an inline formula), you'll see:

```
> \OMS/cmsy/b/n/10 .
```

as in the output of `\showoutput` (except for the size, because the footnote symbol at the bottom of the page is set using `\@textsuperscript` which does `\fontsize\sf@size\z@`). Finally, `\showoutput` mentions character `{` which is indeed in position `"7B` in the OMS encoding (see page 33 of [encguide.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/doc/encguide.pdf), usually accessible with `texdoc fontenc`).

In your file, the symbols that miss a bold variant in the requested size are `\twonotes` and `\eighthnote` from `wasysym`. It doesn't appear necessary to me to force them to be bolder than they already are when comparing them with the other symbols, but if you *really* want to apply a “poor man's bold” technique to them, you can do:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter

\newlength{\bshft}              % shifting amount to create fake bold
\setlength{\bshft}{0.15pt}

\newrobustcmd*{\fakebold}[1]{%
  {\ooalign{#1\cr
  \kern-\bshft#1\cr
  \kern\bshft#1}}%
}

\newrobustcmd*{\twonotesbold}{\fakebold{\twonotes}}
\newrobustcmd*{\eighthnotebold}{\fakebold{\eighthnote}}

\newcommand*{\myfnsymbolsingle}[1]{%
(...) % what follows: same as you already have, except for
      % \twonotes and \eighthnote, as specified below
```

then replace:

- the three occurrences of `\twonotes` with `\twonotesbold`, and
- the three occurrences of `\eighthnote` with `\eighthnotebold`.

Comment: thanks a lot!! Can I avoid these problems by using the `fakebold` code? Do you know how can I use it? `\def\fakebold#1{\ThisStyle{\ooalign{$\SavedStyle#1$\cr%
  \kern-\bshft$\SavedStyle#1$\cr%
  \kern\bshft$\SavedStyle#1$}}}`

Comment: Please see my last edit. I don't think it is necessary here, but I provided a way based on that code (modified so that it works...).

Comment: excellent!!! Thanks!!!