# Different custom footnote symbol on the same page

Tags: footnotes

I have redefined the footnote symbol in the preamble as follows:

```latex
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\color{black}$\spadesuit$}
\newcommand{\txtn}{\textnormal}
```

Now I have some text, a footnote, and then some more text where I want another footnote, but I want a different symbol (so the reader knows which footnote I'm referring to). How do I redefine the footnote symbol without redefining it globally?

```latex
\[(x^a)^{-1} = (\underbrace{x \cdot x \cdot \ldots \cdot x}_{a \txtn{ terms}})^{-1} = \footnote{\tiny By exercise 15.} (x^{-1} \cdot x^{-1} \cdot \ldots \cdot x^{-1})^a = \footnote{different symbol for this footnote} x^{-a}.\]
```

I expect there to be some kind of command such as `\footnote[\symbol]{footnote}`.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/826/symbols-instead-of-numbers-as-footnote-markers for some general stuff; in your case I would suggest instead of defining `\thefootnote` as what you did, you can define `\thefootnote` to be `\fnsymbol{footnote}` and redefine `\@fnsymbol` as shown https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78221/changing-footnote-symbols (replacing the symbols appropriately). If you make the footnote counter reset per page, then the first time on every page it will show the spadesuit symbol and so on.

Comment: Alternatively, you can look into the `footmisc` package. It has commands to help you define a collection of symbols, and you can access them either in order, or by calling `\footnote[3]{footnote}` for the 3rd symbol you defined and so on.

Comment: you could upload a handrawn sketch of the desired output

Comment: @js bibra I don't understand.