# How to get symbols for \thanks command with Thesis class

Tags: symbols, footnotes, thesis

I'm having a slight problem with regards to the `\thanks` command.

My preamble is the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{Thesis}  % Use the "Thesis" style, based on the     ECS Thesis style by Steve Gunn
\graphicspath{{Figures/}}  % Location of the graphics files (set up for graphics to be in PDF format)

% Include any extra LaTeX packages required
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}  % Use the "Natbib" style for the references in the Bibliography
\usepackage{verbatim}  % Needed for the "comment" environment to make LaTeX comments
 \usepackage{vector}  % Allows "\bvec{}" and "\buvec{}" for "blackboard" style bold vectors in maths
\usepackage{graphicx}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, colorlinks=true}  % Colours hyperlinks in blue, but this can be distracting if there are many links
```

In the author section I have the following:

```
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
\emph{Author:}\\
 John \textsc{Smith}
 \thanks{Student at the University of Cape Town}
 \end{flushleft}
 \end{minipage}
  ~
 \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
 \begin{flushright} \large
  \emph{Supervisor:} \\
  Dr. John \textsc{Doe\thanks{Lecturer at the University of Cape Town}} % Supervisor's Name
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}\\[2cm]
```

I then get the following output

[image]

But I don't want the number, I want the symbols, like in the example here:
http://wiki.contextgarden.net/LaTeX_Thanks

Comment: Does Stefan’s solution from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/826/symbols-instead-of-numbers-as-footnote-markers help?

Comment: News? Did any of the solutions to the linked question help?