# Make all footnotes numbered subsequently, but one with a symbol

Tags: symbols, footnotes

I was wandering if there's a way to make only one footnote appear with a symbol (*) instead of the number.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Please also have a look at [Symbols instead of numbers as footnote markers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/830/4012) – in the comments to Stefan’s answer, you’ll see how to change this for just one Footnote.

Comment: @doncherry: Oh, I guess this is the better duplicate.

Comment: @Speravir I guess ... unless the OP wants exactly one footnote with one specific symbol, that might be far enough from both questions to justify a separate question, i.e. I would expect a good answer to be more than an amalgamate of the answers to these two questions.

Comment: @Speravir exactly, I need only one footnote to have a symbol. I have note 1-9 numbered, one "asterisked" note and then note 10 and so on

Comment: @pierpaolo Could you [edit] your question to describe this situation, with the example you just gave and optimally even with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) with a few footnotes, each specifying what kind it should be?

Comment: Are you using [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) or any packages that modifies the display/formatting of footnotes?

Answer (score 17):

If you're not using anything fancy in your document (like [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), say), you can redefine `\@xfootnote`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\setlength{\textheight}{.3\textheight} Just for this example
\makeatletter
\def\@xfootnote[#1]{%
  \protected@xdef\@thefnmark{#1}%
  \@footnotemark\@footnotetext}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
This is a\footnote{Regular footnote} piece of text.
This is a\footnote[*]{Different footnote} piece of text.
This is a\footnote{Regular footnote} piece of text.
This is a\footnote{Regular footnote} piece of text.
This is a\footnote[$\dagger$]{Different footnote} piece of text.
This is a\footnote{Regular footnote} piece of text.
This is a\footnote[$\star$]{Different footnote} piece of text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wouldn’t it be semantically nicer to use `\textdagger` and something like `\textasteriskcentered` or one of `bbding`’s or `pifont`’s stars instead of the math mode versions?

Comment: @doncherry: I followed the basic definition of `\@fnsymbol` in [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx).

Comment: @Werner It seems to be working fine with `hyperref` on my end (with `hyperfootnotes=true`). Is there a particular reason to expect clashes?

Comment: @triple_sec: I know that [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) changes/taps into a large number of document elements, so was concerned that it would influence that if redefining `\@xfootnote`. If it works, then go ahead; I probably didn't test it extensively.

Comment: @Werner I see—I do know what you’re talking about, `hyperref` can easily wreak havoc. I thought you had identified a specific clash, though. I didn’t check thoroughly, either, but, for what it’s worth, I identified no error message in the console and the output looked very nice. The custom symbols even had clickable hyperlinks attached to them! This is an elegant solution, thank you very much!