# Two types of footnotes, context sensitive

Tags: footnotes

I would like to use two types of footnotes. The first are standard footnotes used throughout the body of the text and which are numbered sequentially. The second are footnotes used in a few chapter titles, which I want to have a single static symbol (e.g. *), these should not increment and should not interact with nor affect the bodytext footnotes.

If possible, and a simple method exists, I would like to avoid using another package.

I had thought of using `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext`, but I am not sure how. Any suggestions?

Comment: Check this question, I think your is a duplicate: [Make all footnotes numbered subsequently, but one with a symbol](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/158973/4778).

Comment: "Another" package?  If you don't like packages, LaTeX probably isn't for you -- it uses packages by design. A [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)) would probably be helpful: footnotes are trickier than you might think, and you are likely omitting telling us something by accident.

Comment: @Alenanno: Thank you, the answer that you suggested was just what I was looking for, but hadn't been able to find in my previous search of the stackexchange.

Comment: @jon: don't get me wrong, I love packages, but sometimes, as when writing a thesis that incorporates many previously written documents, each using a large number of packages, I get concerned about conflicts and package compatibility issues (which I have encountered in the past).

Comment: Indeed: though you should always 're-factor' your preamble when incorporating older documents. Cargo cult programming is an insidious thing, and best avoided. The advantage of LaTeX is its packages, provided you are using well-designed ones. Packages that everyone uses all the time are *less* likely to cause conflicts than ad hoc solutions -- which no package writer can reasonably be expected to anticipate. Provided you aren't using unmaintained packages from 1994 or things you got from a friend of a friend and so on, you're usually OK. And if you do find a conflict, report it! That's useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `manyfoot` package, from the `ncctools` bundle, or the `bigfoot` package, which adds more customisation possibilities. They work adding a suffix to the `\footnote` family commands.