# How to change the definition of footnotes without \makeatletter and \makeother

Tags: footnotes

I want to change the definition of footnotes in order to be able to change the footnote symbol for some footnotes (the footnotes corresponding to the authors of a paper). I tried the recommendation of the first answer of this thread:
[Make all footnotes numbered subsequently, but one with a symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158973/make-all-footnotes-numbered-subsequently-but-one-with-a-symbol)

I use the Dissertate class (https://github.com/suchow/Dissertate) and there this code doesn't work, since Latex complains about the use of `\@`:

```
Use of \@ doesn't match its definition.
```

Comment: What is the problem with `\makeatletter...\makeatother`? You could make the change in an own package file -- you don't need `\makeatletter...\makeatother` then

Comment: since the recommendation in the linked question is to redefine the command `\@xfootnote`, `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` are required.

Comment: If I run Werner's document with the `dissertate` class instead of `article`, I get no error. Can you show a minimal example? However, the footnotes are not numbered with that class, so I don't understand what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the point in not using the `\makeatletter...\makeatother` pair but if really necessary: Here's a package based wrap around (I stole the full code from Werner's answer in the given link [Make all footnotes numbered subsequently, but one with a symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158973/make-all-footnotes-numbered-subsequently-but-one-with-a-symbol) ;-) -- but the splitting is by me)

withoutatletter.sty:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\ProvidesPackage{withoutatletter}


\def\@xfootnote[#1]{%
  \protected@xdef\@thefnmark{#1}%
  \@footnotemark\@footnotetext}

\endinput
```

And here the `foo.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{withoutatletter}
\begin{document}
This is a\footnote{Regular footnote} piece of text.
This is a\footnote[*]{Different footnote} piece of text.
This is a\footnote{Regular footnote} piece of text.
This is a\footnote{Regular footnote} piece of text.
This is a\footnote[$\dagger$]{Different footnote} piece of text.
This is a\footnote{Regular footnote} piece of text.
This is a\footnote[$\star$]{Different footnote} piece of text.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

For code in a class or package `@` is already a letter so if you go

```
\makeatletter
... new code
\makeatother
... rest of original code
```

then the rest of the original code is broken as `@` is no longer a letter.

`\makeatletter` is intended for use in teh *preamble* for short sections of code to avoid needing to make a package or class file so

```
\documentclass{yourclass}
\makeatletter
... new code
\makeatother

 ... rest of _document_ with @ not a letter
```