# Footnotes with a symbol in section headings

Tags: table-of-contents, footnotes

I would like to combine [a method of customising footnote symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158988/31839) which allows for commands like:

`\footnote[*]{foo}`

with [a method of putting footnotes into section titles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123762/31839) so that they don't show up in the Table of Contents.

If have tried simply putting the two methods together:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@xfootnote[#1]{\protected@xdef\@thefnmark{#1}\@footnotemark\@footnotetext}
\makeatother
\makeatletter
\def\titlefootnote{\ifx\protect\@typeset@protect\expandafter\footnote\else\expandafter\@gobble\fi}
\makeatother
```

and this allows me to do, for example:

```
\section{My new section\titlefootnote[*]{This section has footnotes}}
```

but the table of contents then reads:

**1   My new section*]This section has footnotes**

How can I adjust the code to allow for the `\footnote[*]`-type command *and* the `\titlefootnote` tweak?

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
% Allow footnotes to chapter (and other heading) titles without them
% appearing in the table of contents and running titles at the top of the page
\makeatletter
\def\@xfootnote[#1]{\protected@xdef\@thefnmark{#1}\@footnotemark\@footnotetext}
\makeatother
\makeatletter
\def\titlefootnote{\ifx\protect\@typeset@protect\expandafter\footnote\else\expandafter\@gobble\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{My new section\titlefootnote[*]{This section has footnotes}}
\end{document}
```

[image: Title footnotes]

*(by the way, I know [some people](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/153340/31839) say you shouldn't use footnotes in a section title.)*

Comment: Have you tried the optional argument of `\section`, as in `\section[My new section]{My new section\titlefootnote{...}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in my comment, the use of the optional argument of `\section` can avoid the footnote in the toc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\@xfootnote[#1]{\protected@xdef\@thefnmark{#1}\@footnotemark\@footnotetext}
\makeatother
\makeatletter
\def\titlefootnote{\ifx\protect\@typeset@protect\expandafter\footnote\else\expandafter\@gobble\fi}
\makeatother
\textheight 2in% FOR DEMONSTRATION PURPOSES ONLY
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\noindent\hrulefill

\section[Title]{Title\titlefootnote[*]{my footnote}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a pretty good solution. There's obviously a risk of mismatches between chapter titles and table of contents due to lack of [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) but I'm happy to put up with this limitation.

Comment: @LondonRob DRY can be avoided with this: `\def\DRY{Section Title}
\section[\DRY]{\DRY\titlefootnote[*]{my footnote}}`