# Footnote in minipage switches from numbers to letters

Tags: footnotes, minipage

Using `\footnotemark` in a minipage with `\footnotetext` uses numbers to mark the footnote and letters to label the foot note text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
This\footnotemark[3] is a test\footnotemark[2].
\footnotemark[3]{test}
\footnotetext[2]{two}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: produces]
Can this be fixed?

I looked at these questions ([2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145304/improper-symbol-mark-of-footnote-in-minipage-environment) and [3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278276/change-footnote-symbol-in-minipage)) and played around with

```
\usepackage{footmisc}
\renewcommand\thempfootnote{\fnsymbol{mpfootnote}}
```

but couldn't work it out.

Comment: Possibly related? [Can I get a normal footnote in a minipage environment in LaTeX? How?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/274/134144)

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\arabic{mpfootnote}}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
This\footnotemark[3] is a test\footnotemark[2].
\footnotetext[3]{test}
\footnotetext[2]{two}
\end{minipage}
```

\end{document}

[image: solution]

The line `\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\arabic{mpfootnote}}` is what I was missing. Footnotes within minipage environments are printed with small letters (noted by Stefan Kottwitz in this question  [\footnotemark and \footnotetext in minipage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/956/footnotemark-and-footnotetext-in-minipage?rq=1)). Willie Wong provided the solution.