# footnote symbol in Beamer

Tags: beamer, symbols, footnotes

In a Beamer frame how can I make a footnote with symbol (such as †)?
I have tried options from this [Symbols instead of numbers as footnote markers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/826/symbols-instead-of-numbers-as-footnote-markers) 
However they don't work for Beamer and I still get text superscript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modified to suit the new wish of the OP. Works but ugly, IMHO.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\ifcase\value{footnote}\or(\$)\or
(\$\$)\or(\$\$\$)\or(\$\$\$\$)\or(\#)\or(\#\#)\or(\#\#\#)\or(\#\#\#\#)\or(\#\#\#\#\#)\fi}
\makeatletter
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Text\footnote{Text of the footnote}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Remove the brackets if you just want a `$` sign.

Comment: How can I change the symbol from * to $ (for example)?

Comment: See the modified answer.

Comment: This seems to not work if using a theme and the text is inside a box like `theorem`.  For instance with `\usetheme{Madrid}`  and `\begin{theorem}` / `\end{theorem}` around the footnoted text, the footnote symbol is a lower-case letter, and this code does not affect it.

Comment: @NateEldredge In that case you can always use the `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` construct, with the `\footnotetext` outside the block.