# Symbols instead of foonotes numbers

Tags: footnotes

I have already seen such questions here, but I need a different solution here.
Could someone please explain me, how can I change numbers of my footnotes to the multiple symbols, e.g. `*, **,***`  etc. without creating errors and chaos in the .tex code?

Thank you!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item Hello, I am the first sentence!\footnote{Ummh.. Looks good with a text!}
\item $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \ \exists m: n=2m\footnote{I am the second footnote, and not a $m^2$ expression.} \lor n=2m+1$
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: what's wrong about the answers provided there : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/826/symbols-instead-of-numbers-as-footnote-markers/ ?

Comment: @jfbu, the post in the link you presented has 5 answers.
The 1. answer explains how to create footnotes with an optional parameter [num] that I do not need, as symbols can be programmed without packages.
The 2. answer offers switches that I do not need.
The 3. : I have only 3-4 footnotes per page and wil not use alphalph that offers AA AB etc...
The 4: I do not understand your answer, @jfbu, as I ask myself what `\makeatletter, \makeatother, \@addtoreset` are, as much as why do you use `\#` and `*` for defining the command.
The 5: counters are important, but it its an another question.

Comment: well, I see you have read them all ;-) the `\#` and `*` are arbitrary choices as mentioned in the answer. To use `@` in control sequence names, one needs the `\makeatletter/\makeatother`. The `\@addtoreset` has a pretty self-explanatory name, and perhaps there is an interface without the `@`. As pointed out in a comment, the resetting of footnote counter as the page changes sometimes has glitches, due to the way TeX ships out pages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The typical symbol-like style of `\footnote`s are defined in the [LaTeX kernel](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?view=co) in the following way:

```
\def\@fnsymbol#1{%
   \ifcase#1\or \TextOrMath\textasteriskcentered *\or
   \TextOrMath \textdagger \dagger\or
   \TextOrMath \textdaggerdbl \ddagger \or
   \TextOrMath \textsection  \mathsection\or
   \TextOrMath \textparagraph \mathparagraph\or
   \TextOrMath \textbardbl \|\or
   \TextOrMath {\textasteriskcentered\textasteriskcentered}{**}\or
   \TextOrMath {\textdagger\textdagger}{\dagger\dagger}\or
   \TextOrMath {\textdaggerdbl\textdaggerdbl}{\ddagger\ddagger}\else
   \@ctrerr \fi
}%
```

When printing the footnote *number*, it conditions on the value of the counter using `\ifcase`, and each possible outcome is listed in the sequential order of the counter.

We can follow the same approach using `*`s:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\ifcase\value{footnote}
  \or *% 1
  \or **% 2
  \or ***% 3
  \or ****% 4
  \or *****% 5
  \or ******% 6
  \or *******% 7
  \or ********% 8
  \or *********% 9
  \else \arabic{footnote}\fi}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item First item\footnote{First footnote}
  \item Second item\footnote{Second footnote}
  \item Third item\footnote{Third footnote}
  \item Fourth item\footnote{Fourth footnote}
  \item Fifth item\footnote{Fifth footnote}
  \item Sixth item\footnote{Sixth footnote}
  \item Seventh item\footnote{Seventh footnote}
  \item Eighth item\footnote{Eighth footnote}
  \item Ninth item\footnote{Ninth footnote}
  \item Last item\footnote{Last footnote}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

It does get a bit unwieldy for large footnote *numbers*, as the asterisks butt into the margin.

Comment: Thank you very much, Werner! It looks grate! I have max. only 3-4 foonotes per page and use a lot of mathematics. I thought `asterisk`s are the best choice for this. 

Could you please give me an advice about how could I get familiar with the kernel code you presented above? I can use LaTeX for my needs, but this code seems to be some kind of an `alien language` for me at the moment.

Thank you!

Comment: @Kirill: The kernel would be daunting then. The code is documented (to some extent) in [`source2e.pdf`](https://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf).

Comment: Did you mean ['butt'](https://www.wordnik.com/words/butt) (the verb), instead of 'but' (the conjunction)? I changed it, but please make sure I got the meaning right.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want to use the `footmisc` package so the footnote “numbers” are reset at each page. Here I define a maximum of four footnotes for a page, using more will raise an error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry} % just for getting small pictures
\usepackage[perpage,symbol*]{footmisc}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\DefineFNsymbols*{asterisks}{{*}{**}{***}{****}}
\setfnsymbol{asterisks}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item Hello, I am the first sentence!\footnote{Ummh.. Looks good with a text!}
\item $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ $\exists m: n=2m\footnote{I am the second
  footnote, and not a $m^2$ expression.} \lor n=2m+1$
\end{itemize}
\newpage
\begin{itemize}
\item Hello, I am the first sentence!\footnote{Ummh.. Looks good with a text!}
\item $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ $\exists m: n=2m\footnote{I am the second
  footnote, and not a $m^2$ expression.} \lor n=2m+1$
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

The usage of `geometry` is just to make small pictures for showing the output.

[image]

Side note. When you seem to need `\<space>` in a math formula, ask yourself if you actually have *two* formulas, like in this case. And, please, don't inflict footnotes in math mode to your readers: they're very ambiguous.