# LaTeX insert one unnumbered footnote using symbol

Tags: pdftex, footnotes

I am working on a book and would like to insert one unnumbered footnote (i.e., suspend the footnote count and use a colored asterisk as the marker).

I have what I think are the requisite packages loaded, and I've tried various solutions from SE (e.g., [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/826/symbols-instead-of-numbers-as-footnote-markers?rq=1), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30602/change-footnote-numbering-temporarily), and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333520/symbols-instead-of-foonotes-numbers)), but to no avail.

I'm also doing this in a two-column text (the footnote should be a single column spanning the page width) inside a self-defined `enumerate` environment.

Answers like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/574134/choose-footnote-symbol-double-asterisk) change the footnotes globally, and I'm trying make the change just once (i.e., reset the footnote counter to 0, change from arabic numerals to symbols, change the color from black to red, insert the rogue footnote, and return everything to the state it was in just prior to this).

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=9pt, twoside, final, openright, c6paper]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{parskip}                        
\usepackage[flushmargin, symbol*]{footmisc}     
\usepackage{multicol}   
\usepackage{ragged2e}         
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}           
\usepackage{enumitem}   

% FN symbol definition
\DefineFNsymbolsTM{myfnsymbols}{% def. from footmisc.sty "bringhurst" symbols
  \textasteriskcentered *
  \textdagger    \dagger
  \textdaggerdbl \ddagger
  \textsection   \mathsection
  \textbardbl    \|%
  \textparagraph \mathparagraph
}%

% New double-enumerate definition:
\newlist{bienumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlistdepth{4}
\setlist[bienumerate, 1]{%
  label=\arabic*\additionallabel.,
  wide,
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\additionallabel}{}{}
\NewDocumentCommand{\biitem}{o}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{%
    \renewcommand{\additionallabel}{}%
  }{%
    \renewcommand{\additionallabel}{ (#1)}%
  }%
  \item
}


\definecolor{darkred}{HTML}{AE0000}
\newcommand{\cdr}{\color{darkred}}

\begin{document}


\setcounter{footnote}{0}

\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

\begin{Center}
{\cdr {\textsc{Caput III}}}

DE CALENDARIO ADHIBENDO \\ IN RECITATIONE DIVINI OFFICII
\end{Center}
\begin{bienumerate}[itemsep=-0.75ex, leftmargin=0ex, itemindent=1em, parsep=3pt]
\biitem[156] In domibus interprovincialibus, nationalibus, et internationalibus 
Ordinis, pro absolutione divini Officii in choro vel in communi, adhibendum est 
calendarium proprium Ordinis universi, additis tantum festis propri\ae\ ecclesi\ae\ 
(n.~42) necnon festis de quibus n.~50.\footnote{Test test test.}
\end{bienumerate}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Please don't show code snippets we have to combine and extend somehow to get working code. Always show a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, that can be used directly and without any change to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Corrected; see updated question.