# Alternating symbols and numbers as footnote markers

Tags: footnotes

In the example below, I would like the first footnote to have as a marker the symbol *, all the remaining footnotes in the document to have normal Arabic enumeration starting from 1.

I am trying to follow the answer given at
[Symbols instead of numbers as footnote markers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/826/symbols-instead-of-numbers-as-footnote-markers)
without much success.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

```
\documentclass[preprint,1p,times]{elsarticle}

\journal{Some Journal}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frontmatter}
        \title{Some Title}

        \renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

        \author{Fabio\footnote{I want this footnote to have an asterisk}}

        \setcounter{footnote}{0}
        \renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}

        \begin{abstract}
            This is the abstract\footnote{I want this footnote to have a number}
        \end{abstract}

        \begin{keyword}
            keyword1 \sep keyword2
        \end{keyword}

    \end{frontmatter}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this document class, the footnotes in `\author` have no effect on the rest of the document.  You don't need to reset the counter or restore `\thefootnote`.

```
\documentclass[preprint,1p,times]{elsarticle}

\journal{Some Journal}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frontmatter}
        \title{Some Title}

        \author{\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}%
          Fabio\footnote{I want this footnote to have an asterisk}}

        \begin{abstract}
            This is the abstract\footnote{I want this footnote to have a number}
        \end{abstract}

        \begin{keyword}
            keyword1 \sep keyword2
        \end{keyword}

    \end{frontmatter}

\end{document}
```