# Differentiate between footcite and footnote

Tags: symbols, numbering, footnotes

I have this in my preamble so that \autocite makes footnotes:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, autocite=footnote]{biblatex}
```

The problem comes when I want to make a regular footnote to explain something. Regular footnotes and footnotes for citations use the same numbering so it is confusing for the reader. How can I use different numbering for regular footnotes and footcites? Or how do I differentiate between these types of footnotes?

Minimal working example with bibliography:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp, autocite=footnote]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

foo\autocite{key}

bar\footnote{Explaining text}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could change the numbering scheme of footnotes using for example `\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}` (letters) or `\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}` (symbols). Please also extend your code snippet to a full [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: Short answer (because of missing [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)): → [`manyfoot`](https://ctan.org/pkg/manyfoot)

Comment: @leandriis I tested [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/830/151736) answer which seems to be the same as your solution but it changes the numbering for both footcite and footnote. My problem was that I want to separate them from each other somehow.

Comment: @LeoEricson: You are completely right. I have been overlooking that the commands affect both numberings. To differentiate them you should definitely give the package `manyfoot` a try, as already recommended by Schweinebacke. You can then influence the numbering scheme of `footcites` and `footnotes` separately by commands similar to the ones in my first comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if it a good idea to separate the footnote. In general I prefer it if there is only one footnote type where one has to search the note. But it can be done with manyfoot e.g. like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp, autocite=footnote]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage{manyfoot}
\newfootnote{A}
\newcounter{footnoteA}
\newcommand{\footnoteA}{%
\stepcounter{footnoteA}%
\Footnotemark\thefootnoteA \FootnotetextA{}}
\renewcommand{\thefootnoteA}{\alph{footnoteA}}
\begin{document}

foo\autocite{herrmann}

bar\footnoteA{Explaining text}

blalb\autocite{doody}

blblb\footnoteA{explain more}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think that it would be easier for the reader when it is obvious when there is an actual footnote and not a citation. Citations don't add to the reading but footnotes do.

Edit. also I saw that manyfoot has a new command \DeclareNewFootnote which seems to be more concise