# Formatting of symbols used as footnote markers

Tags: footnotes, babel

I've managed to use symbols instead of numbers as footnote markers, with the help of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/826/symbols-instead-of-numbers-as-footnote-markers). However, the footnote markers thus generated are formatted like numbers, instead of like symbols generated with `\thanks{}` (see picture below). Is there a way to obtain the same formatting as the `\thanks{}` command, without actually using it?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[french]{babel}

\begin{document}
\title{My title\thanks{My thanks 1}\thanks{My thanks 2}}
\maketitle

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\footnote{Symbol 1}
\footnote{Symbol 2}

\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}
\setcounter{footnote}{0}
\footnote{Note 1}
\footnote{Note 2}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: `\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\textsuperscript{\fnsymbol{footnote}}}` should do the trick

Comment: note that by default the footnote symbols would be raised, the non-raised symbols followed by `.` is set up by the `french` option of `babel` (try your test file without that line) so someone thinks that is the french style?

Comment: there seems to be a FrenchFootnotes=false option set up in `french.ldf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

You can tell the babel french style not to use this style of footnotes and use the default style:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[french]{babel}

\frenchsetup{FrenchFootnotes=false}%<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
\title{My title\thanks{My thanks 1}\thanks{My thanks 2}}
\maketitle

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\footnote{Symbol 1}
\footnote{Symbol 2}

\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}
\setcounter{footnote}{0}
\footnote{Note 1}
\footnote{Note 2}

\end{document}
```