# Foot note symbol not working

Tags: footnotes

I want to change the foot note symbol to daggers.

I have followed the instructions in the following thread [Symbols instead of numbers as footnote markers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/826/symbols-instead-of-numbers-as-footnote-markers)
and added the following:

```
\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
```

It does not work. The following line just produces the number "n" instead of the symbol it supposedly points to:

```
\footnote[n]{text}.
```

Anyone have any idea why its not working?

Comment: Please provide a MWE (minimal working example) following the demands you find here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/231952, so that we can better understand the problem you are encountering. If you compile this MWE, the output is as expected: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
\begin{document}
Text\footnote[2]{Text}
\end{document}`

Comment: What does `n` refer to here? Surely a number, but is it just any number? Like `123456`, say? A small number, or a large number?