# How to use a symbol in a footnote?

Tags: footnotes

I want to use a symbol say `\dagger` in my article an then want to mention it as a footnote.

I have used the package

```
\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
```

Then I used `\footnote[$\dagger$]{text}` in order to make it as footnote.

But is is giving error.

Any help please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in `[]` should be the number.

```tex
\footnote[num]{text}
```

and

```
1   asterisk        *   2   dagger      †   3   double dagger       ‡
4   section symbol  §   5   paragraph   ¶   6   parallel lines      ‖
7   two asterisks   **  8   two daggers ††  9   two double daggers  ‡‡
```

as is pointed out in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/829/234654.

So the command you need to use is `\footnote[2]{text}`.